# Automatically setting DSCP on guest vs employee network

Tags: vlan, dscp

I am working on a 5000 device network (2/3 wifi, 1/3 wired).  Half of the wifi connections are guests - so their traffic priority should be lower than the employee traffic.

Is there a way to force dscp settings onto guest traffic automatically (without having to setup / configure each guest)?  I'm not worried about particular ports/services used by the guest, I want ALL of their traffic lower priority.

I don't know if DHCP or 802.1x can push out DSCP settings respected by the end user device?  Do I have to enforce/apply these settings at the access points / switches?  etc.  I already have the guests on their on VLAN but what's the RIGHT way to tag their data?

Comment: Lower priority in what sense?

Comment: Quality of Service (QoS)

Comment: ewwhite: Guest traffic should be lower priority than Employee traffic.

Comment: Davidw: QoS will prioritize the packets based on DSCP - the question is how/where best to set the DSCP bits.